# Drag and Drop WPF Not Allowing Me to Drag Left or Up

Tags: wpf, visual-studio

am trying to implement drag and drop in WPF. The code I have now allows me to click the upper left hand corner of a button and drag it down or to the right.

For some reason, it will not allow me to drag to the left or up, and I cannot seen to figure out why.

The code is below:

```
private void ctlTextbox_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    //In this event, we get current mouse position on the control to use it in the MouseMove event.
    FirstXPos = e.GetPosition(sender as Control).X;
    FirstYPos = e.GetPosition(sender as Control).Y;
    FirstArrowXPos = e.GetPosition((sender as Control).Parent as Control).X - FirstXPos;
    FirstArrowYPos = e.GetPosition((sender as Control).Parent as Control).Y - FirstYPos;
}

private void ctlTextbox_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        (sender as FrameworkElement).SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, 
            e.GetPosition((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent as FrameworkElement).X - FirstXPos);

        (sender as FrameworkElement).SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 
            e.GetPosition((sender as FrameworkElement).Parent as FrameworkElement).Y - FirstYPos);
    }
}
```

The XAML:

```
 <Canvas x:Name="MainGrid" RenderTransformOrigin = "0.499,0.425" AllowDrop="True" >
      <Button x:Name="button" Content="112" Style="{StaticResource RoomButton}" MouseLeftButtonDown="ctlTextbox_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseMove="ctlTextbox_MouseMove"  Height="32" Canvas.Left="69" Canvas.Top="67" Width="65" Margin="0" />
</Canvas>
```

Comment: Aside from your question... what is `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(...)` code supposed to do? `object MovingObject = sender;
    MovingObject = null;`  You set `MovingObject` to sender and then immediately after you set `MovingObject` to null.  I don't see the point.

Comment: Please see edits with the XAML code showing what those functions are intended for

Comment: That still does not solve the dragging left/up problem.

Comment: Of course it doesn't, that is why it's an "aside."  One of the rules here on StackOverflow is that you need to post the most concise code to reproduce the problem, not everything you can copy and paste from your editor.  I understand that you're new, so that's why I'm trying to correct this behavior, so that you don't get unnecessary down-votes and actually get your issue resolved. See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it the following way:

1. Add a private field called `_movingObject` in your `Window`:

   ```
   private FrameworkElement _movingObject;
   ```
2. Modify your XAML to this:

   ```
   <Canvas x:Name="MainGrid" RenderTransformOrigin = "0.499,0.425" AllowDrop="True" 
           Background="Transparent" PreviewMouseMove="CanvasPreviewMouseMove">
       <Button x:Name="button" Style="{StaticResource RoomButton}"
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="UIElementPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" 
               PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp="UIElementPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp" 
               Height="32" Canvas.Left="69" Canvas.Top="67" Width="65" Margin="0" />
   </Canvas>
   ```
3. Add the following handlers in the code-behind:

   ```
   private void UIElementPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       _movingObject = sender as FrameworkElement;
   }

   private void UIElementPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   {
       _movingObject = null;
   }

   private void CanvasPreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
   {
       var mousePos = e.GetPosition(sender as IInputElement);
       if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && _movingObject != null)
       {
           _movingObject.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, mousePos.X);
           _movingObject.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, mousePos.Y);
       }
   }
   ```

The problem was that when you moved your mouse up or left you moved it outside the bounds of the control you were trying to drag, so its `MouseMove` event was not getting called.